# Change image with jQuery on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a trouble with changing images with jQuery.
I have following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="image.png" class="download-image regular-image" />
    <div class="options">
         <p>download</p>
    </div>

    <img src="image.png" class="download-image regular-image" />
    <div class="options">
         <p>download</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and following code to manipulate this markup:

```
$('.regular-image').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
}. function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image.png');
}
```

This code is pretty straightfoward and I have no problem with it but lately I introduced another function to keep active image (i.e one that shows up if element is clicked):

```
$('.download-image').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).next().toggle();
     $('.download-image').removeClass('current');
     $(this).addClass('current');
     if ($('.download-image').hasClass('current')) {
         $(this).hover(function() {
              $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
         }, function() {
              $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
         }
     }
}
```

Idea behind this chunk is simple - I added a `current` class to track what element is being active at the moment and then make its element image to stay the same on hover and mouse out using `image2.png` which represents active state. It works but when I click on another element, previously clicked element doesn't behave like a regular one (i.e it keeps `image2.png` attribute on hover and mouse out instead of acting like it was coded for `.regular-image` class). What I did wrong? I feel like solutio might be stupidly easy and straightforward but I can't find it by myself. Any help or thoughts will be highly appreciated!
Thank you for dedicating you time and have a nice day.

**UPD**

To summarize my post, what I want to reach at the moment is to change `image2.png` back to `image.png` when other image is clicked and make it behave like described `.regular-image` in javascript code (to change it to `image2.png` while hovering and `image.png` while mouse is out)

**UPD 2**

With fellow devs' help I'm almost got behavior I want. I changed `click` event to this:

```
$(".download-image").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $('.download-image').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $(document).delegate('.current','mouseover',function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "/image2.png");
    });
    $(document).delegate('.current','mouseout',function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "/image2.png");
    });
});
```

It works but only when I explicitly hover and mouse out on image, but I need to change `image2.png` back to `image.png` every time when I click on other image.

Comment: Please don't add answers into your questions here, nor add [solved] devices to titles - we don't do that. There's a button at the end of each of your questions that allows you to self-answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have error in your code. Please check below mentioned code.

```
$('.regular-image').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image.png');
});
```

And if you adding image by ajax call then use below mentioned code.

```
$(document).on('.regular-image','hover',function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image.png');
});
```

Data element

```
<img data-default-image='image1.png' src='image1.png' />

$(document).delegate('button','click',function(){
   $(this).closest('img').attr('src',$(this).closest('img').data('default-image'));
});
```

Comment: Just to mention, `.delegate()` has been deprecated. Need to use `.on() ` method if jQuery version is 1.7+

Comment: Sorry but this method doesn't work for me. I do use jQuery greater than 1.7 and tried `.on();` method.

Comment: @PrashantShirke, Thank you for reminding me. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I think with your help I'm almost reached behavior I wish. I used `.on()` method binding it to `mouseover` and `mouseout` events instead of hover, it works but only when I'm explicitly mouse overing and mouse outing an image, but how do I actually get standard image (`image.png`) back when I click on other element?

Comment: So in this case your `other object` is overlaying image?

Comment: Yes, something like this. like assume that `image.png` is grey and `image2.png` is blue and blue is when current element is active. When I click on other element currently clicked element becomes active and changes `image.png` to `image2.png`. I also updated my post with current code. `.delegate()` worked for me, I just noticed that I'm not using jquery higher than 1.7.

Comment: In this case you have to use data elements, and define `data-default-image='image1.png'` and on clicking of another object restore image `attr` with `data-default-image` value

Comment: Thank you for your help Shyam, I appreciate it. I haven't used `data` attribute instead I just explicitly changed src attribute when deleting `.current` class.

Comment: yes its alternative approach, but if you use data attributes, it will work for you in regardless of class. So there will be no dependency of class. but anyways @VadimNovozhilov, Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

instead of

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

also I am frankly do not understand what are you trying to do by the following code:

```
$(this).hover(function() {
              $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
         }, function() {
              $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
         }
```

are you sure there should be two same lines?

Comment: Unfortunately `preventDefault()` doesn't work for me, I can invoke next element (`.options` div) only with `.stopPropagation();` method. When it comes to code you mentioned, I use it as a part of representation of current state like assume that `image.png` is grey and `image2.png` is blue. I tried other ways to make it but only that one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I found out a way to get behavior I want by changing `src` attribute at the same moment when I remove `.current` class. My code looks like this for now:

```
$(".download-image").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $('.download-image').removeClass('current').attr('src', 'image.png');
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $(document).delegate('.current','mouseover',function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
    });
    $(document).delegate('.current','mouseout',function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
    });
});
```